# Solving a differential equation based on integrals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is my first week dealing with Differential Equations, and I am totally lost at solving the following equation:

$\int^x_0(x-t)y(t)dt=2x+\int^x_0y(t)dt$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\int^x_0(x-t)y(t)dt=2x+\int^x_0y(t)dt$ we derive

$$x\int^x_0y(t)dt -\int_0^xty(t)dt=2x+\int^x_0y(t)dt.$$

If we differentiate we get

$$\int^x_0y(t)dt+xy(x)-xy(x)=2+y(x).$$

Hence

$$\int^x_0y(t)dt=2+y(x).$$

Differentiation once again yields

$$y(x)=y'(x).$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thank you so much, Fred. Your answer explains the methodology perfectly. And yeah, based on my one lecture dealing with the topic, I assume that this result would mean that $y(x)=e^x$ :)

Comment: Be careful ! The differential equation $y(x)=y'(x)$ has the general solution $y(x)=ce^x$. From $\int^x_0y(t)dt=2+y(x)$ we deduce that $y(0)=-2.$ Hence $c= ?.$

Comment: Got it… $y(x)=-2e^x$. Thanks so much for your help!